# Joining two tables with different key values

Tags: sql, key, inner-join, openquery

I have two tables:

table 1

```
Name | AMOUNT  | TYPE

John | 20      |  TH 

Jill | 10      |  IU

Bill | 30      |  IK

John | 45      |  AL
```

Table 2

```
TYPE | DESC

88   | RENT

34   | ALIMONY

87   | TAX

56   | BEER
```

I have to join these tables. I know that `TYPE 'TH'` in table 1 corresponds to '88' in table 2.
Similarly, IK corresponds to 87 and so on . But there isn't any reference table which says so which I could use for joining these . Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Create a table with rows TH 88, IK 87 etc, if there isn't already one, and use two joins.

Answer (score 0):

If these are the only data contained on the tables you can create a new table, `table3`:

```
   TYPE 1| TYPE2

    88   | TH 

    34   | IU

    87   | IK

    56   | AL
```

And try:

```
select Name,Amount,Type.table1,Type,table2 from  table1 inner join table3
on table1.Type=table3.Type2
inner join
table2 on table2.type=tabl3.type1
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention DBMS but you should be able to use a derived table like:

```
select ...
from t1
join ( values ('TH',88),('IK',87) ) as a (x,y)
    on t1.type = a.x
join t2
    on a.y = t2.type
```

You might have to do something like:

```
join ( select ('TH',88) union all select ('IK',87) ) as a (x,y)
```

instead. But if this relationship exists, why don't create a table for it and insert the information?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a rather strange question because it is against the rules of relational databases. But you can fix it like this:

```
inner join Table2 on Table2.Type = 88 and Table1.Type = 'TH'
```

This you can do for each combination. But I suggest it would be better to add a new column with a reference to the id of the type.

Answer (score 0):

If there exists some good reason for not creating a third table, you can write something like:

```
  SELECT
    ........
  FROM
    table1 a
  JOIN table2 b
  ON
    (
      CASE
        WHEN a.type='TH'
        THEN 88
        WHEN a.type='IK'
        THEN 87
      ...........
      END
    )
    =b.type
```